# Does storing selected/found elements in variable increase performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I created a jQuery plugin to modify my navigation. Unfortunately I have to access and modify almost all child elements such as `<ul>`, `<li>`, `<a>` and so forth. Those elements are then needed between one and four times.

Should I store them all in variables or should I access them like `$('.my-nav').find('li')` or `$('.my-nav').find('li')` when needed?

It just seems like a waste of memory to have 5 variables for maybe 25 lines of code.
But I don't know if this is a acceptable trade-off for more performance.

I created a Fiddle to illustrate what is meant: http://jsfiddle.net/Yj35Q/2/

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the Fiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always good practice to cache your nodes. You can also benchmark yourself using http://jsperf.com/

You don't really need to worry about how much storage space variables need unless you are storing a massive DOM tree or something. Much more relevant the amount of work the JS engine has to do to locate the nodes.

**EDIT**
or even better, you can find an existing test case someone else has already created
http://jsperf.com/ns-jq-cached/4

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly wise to cache your DOM elements where appropriate, whether you're using jQuery or not.

But this question got me thinking that maybe we should have a plugin to help with this.  I searched around and couldn't find one.

So I wrote one really quick.  It's a [lazy loading jQuery selector](http://blog.bucketsoft.com/2012/05/lazy-loading-jquery-selector.html)...

```
(function($){
    var cachedObjects = new Array();

    $.lazy = function(selector) {
        if (typeof selector != "string" || arguments.length > 1) 
            return $.apply(this, arguments);

        var o = cachedObjects[selector];
        if (o == undefined)
        {
            o = $(selector);
            cachedObjects[selector] = o;
        }

        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You'd use it like this...

```
$.lazy('.my-nav').show();
```

Let me know if I've overlooked anything.  But I believe this would be good to use whenever the elements you're selecting are static and are never added or removed dynamically.

**UPDATE**

I've changed the code to make this more efficient.  And I've added a line to `return $(selector)` when the selector is not a string.  So the caching will only work when the selector is a string.

**UPDATE #2**

Now it'll `return $.apply(this, arguments)` when you're not simply passing a string, per  jfriend00's suggestion.

Comment: An interesting thought.  So, instead of `$(selector).fadeOut()`, one uses `$.lazy(selector).fadeOut()`.  I'd suggest you make sure the selector is a string and it could be more efficient when it isn't already cached by not having to look it up again in `cachedObjects` after you just put it in there.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Good thoughts.  I'll make these changes later tonight.

Comment: I'd suggest you change `if (typeof selector != "string") return $(selector);` to: `if (typeof selector != "string" || arguments.length > 1) return $.apply(this, arguments);` so it works for all acceptable jQuery arguments.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Good call, I've made this change too.

Comment: I think I'd called it `$.cache` or `$cache` or something that represents the fact that it's using a cache.  `$.lazy` doesn't do that for me.  You probably want the ability to clear the cache too.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Hmm... well, `lazy` is an indicator of the functionality that's going on behind the scenes.  It's lazy loading and storing in a cache.  Whereas the term cache is typically reserved for storing values and nothing more.  Lazy loading is also explained here... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading  And incidentally, there's also a `Lazy` type that was introduced in C# 4.0 which has this functionality.  So I don't know, lazy makes more sense to me, and I'm thinking it's less likely to have any collisions with jQuery keywords or other plugins in the future.

Comment: I disagree about lazy loading.  It's not lazy loading at all.  It's resolving the selector as soon as you make the function call and no later.  It may be lazy relative to getting them all ahead of time, but to the user of your function, there's nothing lazy about it.  It would be lazy if it wasn't resolving the selector at all until later when a method was called.  That would e lazy.  This is just resolving the selector when requested and putting it in a cache.

Comment: @jfriend00 - But that's what lazy loading is.  Specifically, this is most similar to the lazy initialization examples like what you see on the Wikipedia article.  It sounds like you're referring to deferred execution, which isn't necessarily a characteristic of lazy loading.

Comment: I disagree.  There's nothing lazy about what you're doing and a user of your function isn't going to think about it being lazy.  It's is evaluating the selector **immediately** when called and then caching the result for future requests.  It would be lazy only if it the selector wasn't evaluated until some later after the function call like when a method actually wanted to operate on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. An interesting approach indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Within the same function, I will cache the results of a DOM search in a local variable so I never have to do the same DOM search more than once in the same function.  For most functions this will not be needed, but it's easy and safe to put the result in a local variable only for the duration of the function so I think it's a good habit.

I will usually NOT cache DOM nodes into global variables simply because I try to avoid global variables and it is rarely a performance issue to retrieve the DOM node when needed for a particular function.  Another reason to avoid having DOM references in global variables is that if a particular DOM node gets removed from the DOM and you intend for it to be garbage collected, if there is a reference to it in a global variable, the DOM node will not be garbage collected and could lead to a memory leak.

There are some cases where I am repeatedly looking up the same DOM node (like on a timer) where I will cache the DOM node into a non-global variable in a function closure and then use that variable locally.  But, I find cases where this is needed to be rare.

Comment: +1.  And let me know what you think of my lazy loading jQuery selector.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. As often, multiple answers I want to accept but unfortunately only can one. fritzfromlondon was a little faster.

Comment: @JohnB. - fritzfromlondon's answer and my answer are different answers with different recommendations.  I would think you would vote for the one that makes more sense to you or seems more complete rather than which one came a few minutes before the other.  I'm not objecting to you choosing a different answer than mine, just that your criteria shouldn't be which came first when the answers are different.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right, both your answers are different but the bottom line I was looking for (should I cache or not) was answered by both. Yours had valuable information about scope, his a link to a nice test case. But I can see that my "was a little faster" is giving the wrong impression about the criteria I applied for choosing an answer.